# NULL terminator on string included via AS's incbin directive

Tags: c, embedded-resource, ld, null-terminated

I have some large string resources located in files that I include in my executable. I include them in the executable using the following. The `*.S` allows GCC to invoke `as` to produce the object file without any special processing.

```
    ;; ca_conf.S
    .section .rodata

    ;; OpenSSL's CA configuration
    .global ca_conf
    .type   ca_conf, @object
    .align  8
ca_conf:
ca_conf_start:
    .incbin "res/openssl-ca.cnf"
ca_conf_end:
    .byte 0

    ;; The string's size (if needed)
    .global ca_conf_size
    .type   ca_conf_size, @object
    .align  4
ca_conf_size:
    .int    ca_conf_end - ca_conf_start
```

I add a `.byte 0` after including the string to ensure the string is `NULL` terminated. That allows me to use `ca_conf` as a C `const char*`, or `{ca_conf,ca_conf_size}` as a C++ string.

Will the assembler or linker rearrange things such that the `NULL` terminator could become separated from the string its terminating? Or will the assembler and linker *always* keep them together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're in assembler they will be kept together.
One other point, because of the `ALIGN 4` ca_conf_size may not be the length you are expecting, it can include upto 3 padding bytes.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much. I did not think about alignment affecting size. I've updated the question in case someone else stumbles across the question and copy/paste without reading the comments.